# Translating ER diagram to Relational model

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship, erd

I have a question about the ER diagram below.

[image: ER Diagram]
**Question:** If there are 2 relationships born and live from actor to place entity.

Do they both have the same foreign key which is place_no? So does that mean I just put the foreign key in Actors relational model and that's it or do I have to make a table for Born?

Because an actor is born in a place and lives in a place... so how would it be possible to differentiate between 1 place_no FK?

Comment: There are clearly two relations between the two entities (actor <> place), so in one of the tables you have to use two distinct foreign keys which happen to reference the same attribute in another table.

Comment: so a foreign key in Actors that is named Lives and another one that is named Born?

Comment: OR do i create a table for each relationship for example lives releationship has place_no FK and Lives FK , a_no FK... born releationship has place_fk a_no FK and Born FK?

Comment: Well you have to specify arity of the relationship. I think we can assume that a person was born in just one place - so you don't need a table in between (it's `1:n` relationship), however if you assume that someone can live in many places you are going to need a junction table, since in relational model you can't have `m:n` relationships.

Comment: If i assume m:1 for lives and born releationship then theres just a FK in actors table?

Comment: Yes, since the value stored in the foreign key is atomic, which enforces the `1:` side of the relationship.

Comment: Alright, well how would I be able to have two different names but reference place_no FK at the same time?    I want to create the attributes Born and Lives FK but I don't understand how I can reference it to place_no

Comment: Would it be like this?  FK (Born) references place(place_no) and FK(Lives) references place(place_no)?

Comment: You're welcome, since it's answered the question I'm going to post it as an answer so that you can close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the arity of the relationships. You can map the conceptual `1:n` relationships directly in relational model using just foreign keys. For `n:m` relationships you should use junction tables.

Since it seems that the relationships here are both `n:1` since a person can be born in just one place and (based on your comments) we can also assume that a person can only live in one place at the time we can map these relationships as foreign keys.

As an example in SQL (assuming we have two relations `actor` and `place`, the code is in `CREATE` code of `actor`):

```
[...]
born int REFERENCES place(place_no),
lives int REFERENCES place(place_no),
[...]
```

Comment: Hey I also had another question about 2 other entites in the ER diagram... I wanted to make another post but I can't since I have to wait 90 minutes. If i upload it can you help me out?

Comment: Sure, post it here in the comments, you can copy it over later.

Comment: (I edited the URL from the post to show the whole ERD)
                                                                                                            Question1:If an actor is a Dramatist does that mean I store dramatist_no FK in Actor relational table or put a_no PK in Dramatist table? (or both)

Comment: 1:1 constraint and it is a relationship which is why I am confused... I know how to do the ISA relationship one though.

Comment: I would make something called a weak table - existence of its rows depends on existence of rows of another table. It would have a primary key `dramatist_no` which would also be (at the same time!) a foreign key referencing primary key of `actor` table. This way you enforce that 1) it references the rows from `actor` 2) It's either 0 or 1 at the dramatist side (either row doesn't exist or there is just one since primary keys can't have duplicates) - `CREATE TABLE dramatists(dramatist_no INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES actor(actor_no));`

Comment: Ok so dramatist_no would be a PK and FK then?

Comment: Well there is a condition, a dramatist doesn't have to exist to write a play. There can be  "closet plays"

Comment: I originally made dramatist a table with dramatist_no PK and a_no is a FK from actors

Comment: Can a play be written by more than one dramatist?

Comment: Yeah, its a M:M relationship

Comment: Ok then I guess your solution is correct in this case

Comment: Oh sure it is m:n. I was not familiar with your ERM notation. Then you can always have a nullable foreign key in the junction table. As in the key that references a dramatist can be null. This way it's optional. As to choice of PK I think my solution is a bit simpler since you don't have to support two sets of IDs,

Comment: Ok, that makes sense both solutions made sense I was just trying to see the difference. Also, if a dramatist writes a play does the play table need to store dramatist_no? Or does it not matter since Play does not have any other relationships with dramatist?

Comment: Also is there a potential problem where Dramatist is not able to be represented as a total participation? Because like I said, a dramatist doesn't have to write a play for a play to exist (closet plays). I am not sure if you are familiar with this concepts of "triggers" but I think I may have to say that also requries a trigger?

Comment: Where would you see a trigger being useful here?

Comment: Well, if there is an event where the dramatist does not exist but there is a play written wouldn't that trigger an event?

Comment: Wouldn't that play just not have any dramatist associated with it? What would that trigger do?

Comment: Oh I see where I went wrong... It would be just a null dramatist. Trigger is supposed to check cases but in this case I guess its useless.

Comment: Exactly. Since it's past midnight where I live I'm afraid I won't be able to answer any more of your questions this night, so please consider posting them as separate questions (if there are more of them).